# SAS where to get precision / scale for all "num" columns that store decimal data?

Tags: types, sas

When another team generates output from dictionary_columns and I filter on type = "num": the precision and scale have only 1 value across all columns; "0" and ".", respectively. This is despite the fact that there are dozens if not hundreds of [precision 16, decimal 4] and [precision 16 and decimal 2] as verified by exporting the data. Also, 100% of the type = num columns have [length]= 8.

I've scoured output of dicationary_columns and all manner of SAS support pages. I would expect something like how to either

- export a data dictionary with complete and accurate data type information
- export create table statements for all existing tables with complete and accurate data type information

**The real answer for DBAs**
See SAS documentation on the `format` command; when you supply a format, the value gets stored in the `dictionary.columns.format`. SAS will respect the `format` when you execute %ds2csv; so for dbas:

1. export the dictionary.columns
2. use dictionary.column to generate create table sql
3. for (sas)variable type=char use varchar(sas column length)
4. for (sas)variable type=num use the appropriate integer, decimal(precision, scale) etc. as indicated in the (dictionary.columns.format)

Comment: Please define your terms.  SAS has two types of variables, fixed length character strings and floating point numbers.  Where do you expect to find "precision" and "scale"? Do you have some external metadata about the variables where that is stored?

Comment: I am using SAS's own terms. Do you disagree that dictionary_columns has both precision and scale attributes? see: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjz5dWns5X9AhX9LFkFHY-cD64QFnoECCAQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.sas.com%2Fresources%2Fpapers%2Fproceedings%2Fproceedings%2Fsugi30%2F070-30.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0ZnudROysJlxt1jP0mCutj

Comment: I do not see either of those terms in that paper by Kirk Paul Lafler that you linked.

Comment: at the bottom of page 4 - it is not formatted well. its a picture and the line wraps.

Comment: Those variables are not populated for SAS datasets. They might be populated if the metadata is coming from a query of an external database you have linked your SAS session to.

Comment: SAS isn't a database. It's possible someone is using formats to enforce those concepts within SAS data sets though. A format of 8.2 would mean precision of 8, scale of 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SAS has two type of variables. Fixed length character strings and 64-bit binary floating point numbers.

The LENGTH of a variable is how many bytes it uses to store the value in the dataset.  For a character variable that will match the number of characters when using a single byte encoding. For a numeric variable it is how many of the 8 bytes required to store a 64-bit number you want to store.  When the value is retrieved from the dataset the other bytes are set to binary zeros.  To see how that impacts the maximum integer that SAS can store precisely you can use the CONSTANT() function with the EXACTINT constant.

So on a machine using IEEE format for floating point you get:

```
1487  data _null_;
1488    do bytes=3 to 8;
1489      int=constant('exactint',bytes);
1490      put bytes int comma23. ;
1491    end;
1492  run;

3                   8,192
4               2,097,152
5             536,870,912
6         137,438,953,472
7      35,184,372,088,832
8   9,007,199,254,740,992
```

The values will be different if you are running on an IBM mainframe since that machine uses a different floating point representation.

You can perhaps **impute** an **estimate** of the types of numbers that are being stored based on whether the creator of the dataset decided to attach a specific display format to the variable.  The width of the display format is the number of bytes used to display it.  So that will include space for all digits before and after the decimal point and also for a decimal point if needed (and if using a format like COMMA or DOLLAR or PERCENT then also space for example other characters displays).  The value after the period in the format definition is the number of decimal places to display.  So a format of `8.3` will write 4 digits, a decimal point and then 3 more digits for a total of 8 bytes. So using your definition of PRECISION and SCALE you would estimate the SCALE as the number of decimal places (the value of the FORMATD variable produced by PROC CONTENTS) and PRECISION as either the width of the format (FORMATL variable) or the width minus one depending on whether the number of decimal places is zero or not.

**Note that the format is only used to display the values so it does not change how the values are stored.**

If you want to see the PRECISION and SCALE for the possible values of the normal numeric format (which can be referenced using the alias F) then you could run this program and print the resulting dataset.

```
data decimal;
  length formatspec $40 format $32 formatl formatd precision scale 8;
  format='F';
  do formatl=1 to 17 ;
    do formatd=0 to max(0,formatl-2);
      formatspec=cats(format,formatl,'.');
      if formatd then formatspec=cats(formatspec,formatd);
      scale=formatd ;
      precision = formatl;
      if formatd then precision=precision-1;
      if precision < 17 then output;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

You could do similar calculations for COMMA and DOLLAR formats but including extra subtractions from the PRECISION based on how many extra characters will be printed by those formats.  So DOLLAR13.2 (example displayed value `$1,234,567.89`) would have PRECISION 9 and SCALE 2 since there are 4 punctuation characters counted in the overall width of 13 characters.

If your values could be negative then when converting from PRECISION and SCALE to a SAS display format you probably need to add one to the display width to account for the negative sign.

Comment: with SAS create table statement, you cannot declare a variable to be precision X and scale Y such that attempting to insert / update numbers with/to digits longer that X digits and/or decimals longer than Y digits would generate errors?

Comment: if you need to port a SAS dataset to a relational database system, how would you detect which numeric sas variables need numeric (16,2), vs bit, vs int etc. etc.?

Comment: The same way you would build any database, by asking the owners of the data what the data is.  There are probably papers similar to the one you linked that show SAS methods to query the data and make educated guesses about what it means based on what is in it. For example how many distinct values does a variable have? What is the "cardinality" of the variable? Does each observation have a distinct value then perhaps the variable is a KEY.

Comment: I have never used SAS, so i am relying on your reputation score - but i am dumbfounded that SAS does not provide a way to programmatically define, enforce and report out the precision/scale of numeric variables. The team upstream of me has hundreds of tables with thousands of columns - manually documenting the data type nuances is just not scalable; I am going to run into issues every time we import their data. I guess I will just make every numeric a float? that seems crazy.

Comment: SAS is not a database system. It is an analysis system.  You can link SAS to relational database systems if your data needs require that.

Comment: If they have data that describes the data then you can easily use that to drive your analysis and even generate the code you need to do the analysis.

Comment: I appreciate your replies, just sad they are not solving my issue. I will mark this as an answer eventually if no one else provides something closer to what I need. One more SAS rant - why do the dictionary.columns.precision and dictionary.columns.scale exist if they are never populated? Or if they can be populated, how?

Comment: Because you can connect to a DB that does have precision/scale and in that case you would want the dictionary tables to show that information.

Answer (score 2):

SAS offers interfaces to many RDBMSs called SAS/ACCESS Interface to `<name of RDBMS>`. When creating database tables from SAS data sets, those interfaces generally use a combination of the SAS data type (numeric and character) and the format applied to the SAS variable. For example, I work mostly with Teradata database. The documentation for Teradata has a table that shows what data types are used with certain SAS formats when creating Teradata tables from SAS data sets.

[image]

Notice the last entry in the table. If a numeric variable has any other format applied or no format, then the default data type is float which will capture the value but will probably not be the most efficient storage option.

From my experience, most analysts do not take the time to define formats for every variable unless the data set is heavily used or accessed repeatedly. This info may not help you much.